# Dynamically growing array until user enters 0

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am trying to make a dynamically growing array which increases in size every time the user enters any integer other than 0. When 0 is pressed, it stops taking data from user and the rest of the code is executed.
I tried to implement the growing array through a `do while` loop but it keeps giving me garbage values in my array.

```cpp
int main(){
    int size = 1;
    int* ptr;
    int* ptr1;
    int i = 0;
    int inp;
    ptr = new int[size];
    do{
        ptr1 = new int[size];
        cin >> inp;
        if (inp == 0)
            break;
        else{
            *(ptr + i) = inp;
            size++;
            i++;
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++){
                *(ptr1 + j) = *(ptr + j);
            }
        }
    } while (1);
    for (int k = 0; k < size; k++)
        cout << *(ptr1 + k) << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please always use a programming language tag or nobody will find your question. In this case C++.

Comment: Use `std::vector` if you can. If not, move array growth code to separate function and increase size more than to 1 each time to avoid frequent allocations. And you forget to do `delete[] ptr; ptr = ptr1;` after you copied old contents of array.

Comment: we havent been taught about std : : vector yet and this was just a rough code but i will try to implement what you said. thank you

Comment: `*(ptr + i)` are you required to use that instead of `ptr[i]`?  The `ptr[i]` form is way more widely used although with that said they accomplish the same thing.

Comment: we arent required to use *(ptr+i). if they accomplish the same thing i can just use ptr[i]

Answer (score 0):

When you exit the loop you have already reserved memory again. That is, you have put `ptr1` pointing to a memory address of `size` integers that you have not yet initialized. Also note that when you write `*(ptr + i) = inp;` you are trying to write to memory that you have not allocated. This is because although you increment `ptr1`, you do not do the same with `ptr`.